# Using "about" to specify a quantity

Tags: meaning

When somebody says "this will take me about an hour" or "I ran about four miles", is there an unstated assumption that the actual quantity (time or distance, respectively) will be less than the one specified?

I tend to say, for example, "I ran about four miles" if I actually ran a little less than four miles. But I say "I ran a bit more than four miles" if I actually ran a little more than four miles. Is this distinction unnecessary, and can I use "about" for both meanings?

Comment: *About* generally implies only an approximation, plus or minus. It does not state if sth. is slightly less or slightly more. Compare: *almost*, *nearly*, *quite* etc., that suggest *less than*; *around* that is similar to *about*; *as much as*, *more or less* and similar other terms. *At least* clearly indicates *not less than*.

Comment: You probably say you ran "a bit more than four miles" because you want credit for the extra distance; you say "about four miles" when you didn't run quite that far but want credit for the skipped distance nonetheless. We're really quite good at (often unconsciously) using language to stroke our egos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[About](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/about) (definition 3) simply describes it as *near, close to.* You can use it for exactly that; so long as the actual value is *near* four miles, it doesn't matter if it is under or over. *About* can be used for both.

If you want to be more specific, say I ran *a little over* or *a little under* four miles. If you want to be *really* specific, give an actual numerical value: *I ran 4.2 miles*. (Note: the last option is not entirely practical.)